# I can't get my like query to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a catalog where you can search in based on arguments you give. naam is the name of the product and woord are the given characters. later on in the script i glue this part of the query to the first part.

Thank you

```
if(strlen($whereQuery) > 0) 
    $whereQuery .= 'AND naam LIKE '%'.$woord.'%'';
else
    $whereQuery = 'WHERE naam LIKE '%'.$woord.'%'';
```

Comment: what is the issue exactly?  The title gives no information nor does the actual question.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get to work"? What is the expected result and what are you getting? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use double quote to avoid confusion,

```
if(strlen($whereQuery) > 0) 
    $whereQuery .= " AND naam LIKE '%" .$woord. "%' ";
else
    $whereQuery = " WHERE naam LIKE '%" .$woord. "%' ";
```

or simply,

```
if(strlen($whereQuery) > 0) 
    $whereQuery .= " AND naam LIKE '%$woord%' ";
else
    $whereQuery = " WHERE naam LIKE '%$woord%' ";
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: or just: `$whereQuery = " WHERE naam LIKE '%$woord%' ";` since you are in double quotes anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes.

Or escape the single quotes.

---

Also please do not do what you are currently doing.

[**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes that are part of the query:

```
if(strlen($whereQuery) > 0) 
    $whereQuery .= 'AND naam LIKE \'%'.$woord.'%\'';
else
    $whereQuery = 'WHERE naam LIKE \'%'.$woord.'%\'';
```

Or use a mix of single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Any editor with colour-coding would immediately show you the problem. Just look at your code in the question.

Try this:

```
$whereQuery = ($whereQuery ? $whereQuery." AND" : " WHERE")." naam LIKE '%".$woord."%'";
```

This avoids repeating the whole "LIKE" part twice ;)

Also, make sure you have properly escaped `$woord`. `mysql_real_escape_string` is NOT enough in this case. You also need to run it through `preg_replace("/[%_]/","\\$1",$woord);` to escape special characters in a WHERE clause.